# Can't start clickhouse service, too many files in ../data/default/<TableName>

Tags: database, clickhouse

I have a strange problem with my standalone clickhouse-server installation. Server was running for some time with nearly default config, except data and tmp directories was replaced to separate disk:

```
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/my_config.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<yandex> 
  <path>/data/clickhouse/</path> 
  <tmp_path>/data/clickhouse/tmp/</tmp_path> 
</yandex>
```

Today the server stopped responding with connection refused error. It was rebooted and after that the service couldn't completely start:

```
2018.05.28 13:15:44.248373 [ 2 ] <Information> DatabaseOrdinary (default): 42.86%
2018.05.28 13:15:44.259860 [ 2 ] <Debug> default.event_4648 (Data): Loading data parts
2018.05.28 13:16:02.531851 [ 2 ] <Debug> default.event_4648 (Data): Loaded data parts (2168 items)
2018.05.28 13:16:02.532130 [ 2 ] <Information> DatabaseOrdinary (default): 57.14%
2018.05.28 13:16:02.534622 [ 2 ] <Debug> default.event_5156 (Data): Loading data parts
2018.05.28 13:34:01.731053 [ 3 ] <Information> Application: Received termination signal (Terminated)
```

Really, I stopped process on 57%, because it starts too long(maybe it could start in an hour or two, I didn't try).

The log level by default is "trace", but I didn't show any reasons of such behavior.

I think the problem is in file count in /data/clickhouse/data/default/event_5156. 
Now it is 626023 directories in it and ls -la command do not work in this catalog properly, I have to use find to count files:

```
#  time find . -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
626023

real    5m0.302s
user    0m3.114s
sys     0m24.848s
```

I have two questions:

1)Why Clickhouse-Server generated so much files and directories, with default config?

2)How can I start the service without data loss in adequate time?

Comment: I think it is not a problem of server config, but table partitioning. It was too granular. If even system level tools like ls -la are not working, CH is no magician. I think it won't start even if you wait enough. At least increase limit of open files: `sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=50000000` (it is not permanent!), maybe it will help it to start. Then you could change your schema into bigger partitions. On how to make it load faster - idk.

Comment: Oh, this is not partitioning, it is different tables! Are you sure you need that much tables, not one partitioned table?

Comment: I'd 1) made a backup 2) move out older 80% of tables, 3) start without them 4) made one partitioned table 5) start another CH instance with older tables 6) move rows from old to new (single table) model 7) change application logic to use new table. This is assuming your `event_XXXX` tables are effectively the same table, but different parts.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was in data update method. I used script with jdbc connector and have been sending one string per request. After changing scheme to batch update, the issue was solved.